# Python 3, count letter frequency in file

Tags: python

The line:
for Char in word returns the error "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable"
How did it become an integer and not a string? 
How do I iterate it?

```
# Write a program that reads a file and prints the letters in decreasing
# order of frequency. Your program should convert all the input to lower
# case and only count the letters a-z. Your program should not count
# spaces, digits, punctuation, or anything other than the letters a-z.

import string
from string import digits

fname = input("Enter file:")
if len(fname) < 1 : fname = "romeo-full.txt"
fhand = open(fname)

charcount = dict()

for line in fhand:
    line = line.rstrip()
    line = line.lower()
    line = line.translate(str.maketrans('','',string.punctuation))
    line = str.maketrans("", "", digits)

    for word in line:
        for char in word:
            charcount[char] = charcount.get(char, 0) + 1

print(charcount)
```

Comment: Print out `line` and `word`. What type are they? Read the docs to see what `str.maketrans` returns.

Comment: I think you wanted to to have `line = line.translate(str.maketrans('','',digits))` and you forgot to type `line.translate`

Comment: on a side note, do have a look at `Counter` from `collecctions` module. and also `list(somestring)` will convert `somestring` to a list of characters. So you can achieve the task in one line.

Comment: I think you're making this more complex than necessary with the translations. Here are a few things I would do: 1: use context manager for file i/o (for example `with open(fname) as f`), 2: read the file contents line by line, 3: iterate over the characters in each line, 4: ignoring everything where c.lower() is not in [a-z], increment the counter[c.lower()] in your dict.

Answer (score 0):

```
# prompt the user to enter a file nam
file_name = input('Enter a file name: ')
# this part is just to make testing easier, I want to hit enter, rather than typing in the file name each time
if len(file_name) < 1:
    file_name = 'mbox-short.txt'
# try opening the file
try:
    file_handle = open(file_name)
# if the file is invalid, terminate the program
except:
    print('Invalid File')
    quit()

counts = dict()
# loop through each line in the file
for line in file_handle:
    # convert each line into a list of words
    words = line.rstrip().split()
    # loop through each word in the list
    for word in words:
        # convert each word to lowercase
        word = word.lower()
        # loop through each letter in a word
        for letter in word:
            # letters other than a-z are ignored
            if not 'a' <= letter <= 'z':
                continue
            # create a histogram for letters in a-z. if letter exists, increment its value,
            # otherwise add it to the histogram
            counts[letter] = counts.get(letter, 0) + 1
# sorting histograms happens by comparing the first elements, so we need to create a list
# that stores values first, then the key after it (v, k) so we can compare elements based on v
# since we want them sorted in descending order, reverse=True
temp_list = sorted([(v, k) for (k, v) in counts.items()], reverse=True)
# print the elements where key comes first, then the value after it
for (v, k) in temp_list:
    print(k, v)
```